# Return a ranking points of User follow week, month, year from multiple table with mySQL

Tags: mysql

Here is the structure of my tables:

**User**

```
|--------|------------|
| id     | name       |
|--------|------------|
| 1      | Name1      |
| 2      | Name2      |
| 3      | Name3      |
|--------|------------|
```

**Post**

```
|--------|------------|-------------|--------------------|
| id     | content    | user_id     |   created_at       | 
|--------|------------|-------------|--------------------|
| 1      | Content1   |  1          |2020-01-17 14:03:31 |
| 2      | Content2   |  1          |2020-01-17 16:18:23 |
| 3      | Content3   |  2          |2020-01-17 16:29:13 | 
|--------|------------|-------------|--------------------|
```

**Comment**

```
|--------|------------|-------------|----------|---------------------|
| id     | comment    | user_id     | post_id  |   created_at        |
|--------|------------|-------------|----------|---------------------|
| 1      | Comment1   |  1          |   1      | 2020-01-20 18:29:19 |
| 2      | Comment2   |  1          |   1      | 2020-01-22 17:25:49 |
| 3      | Comment3   |  2          |   2      | 2020-01-28 11:37:59 | 
|--------|------------|-------------|----------|---------------------|
```

**Vote**

```
|--------|-------------|----------|-----------------------|
| id     |  user_id    | post_id  |    created_at         |
|--------|-------------|----------|-----------------------|
| 1      |   1         |   1      | 2020-01-20 15:08:55.0 |
| 2      |   1         |   2      | 2020-01-20 15:13:29   |
| 3      |   2         |   2      | 2020-01-20 15:13:32   |
|--------|-------------|----------|-----------------------|
```

I want to find the top score of 10 users by week, month, the year following to formula:

1. A user creates 1 post will have 10 points.
2. A user creates 1 comment in a post that will have 5 points.
3. A user votes in a post that will have 2 points.

Could anyone help me with this, please!

Thank you so much.

Comment: In addition to what you had listed in your question, please also list the code you generated and show us where it fails. We are ready to extend help from that point. Instead, if you expect anyone to write the whole code for you, it will never help improving your knowledge.

Comment: hint 1: treat the week, month, year as separate queries for a start. hint2: rather than join, `UNION` them in separate queries of the post,comment,vote score hint 3: `group by user_id, week(created_at)`; hint 4: look carefully at the [COUNT function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count).; hint 5: [aggregating by top 10](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1345#104) has this pattern; hint 6: incrementally develop the query; hint 7; start with what the end result will look like

Comment: yes, i got it. But actually, i have no idea :)

Comment: @danblack. Thanks for your instruction.

Comment: Provide a fiddle instead of table-form data (or at least replace it with CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts) and give desired result for this data (descrease TOP 10 to TOP 2 for to decrease source data amount needed).

Comment: @danblack: Given that you've decided to share your hints in the first place, you must have considered them useful enough to do so. I suggest you take it one step further and make them *visible* enough by reposting them as an answer. After all, we are trying to run a Questions & *Answers* site here :) Cheers

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a free coding service website.  You are expected to post the code that you attempted.  If it doesn't work, we can try to help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
select  userId,UsersByWeek,SUM(Score) AS 'Score' FROM
    (
        SELECT  SUM(pCnt + cCnt+ vCnt) AS 'Score,userId,WEEK(createdOn) AS 'UsersByWeek',
                YEAR(createdOn) AS 'UsersByYear',MONTH(createdOn) AS 'UsersByMonth' 
            (
                SELECT  count(p.id)*10 as 'pCnt',u.id as userId,p.created_at as 'createdOn'
                    from  post p
                    left join  user u  ON u.id = p.user_id
                    union 
                 select  count(c.id)*5 as 'cCnt',u.id as userId,c.created_at as 'createdOn'
                    from  comment c
                    left join  user u  ON u.id = c.user_id
                    left join  post p  ON p.post_id = c.post_id
                    union 
                 select  count(v.id)*2 as 'vCnt' as u.id as userId,v.created_at as 'createdOn'
                    from  vote v
                    left join  user u  ON u.id = v.user_id
                    left join  post p  ON p.post_id = v.post_id
            )b
            GROUP BY  userId
            ORDER BY  Score DESC 
    )n
    GROUP BY  UsersByWeeK
    ORDER BY  Score desc
    LIMIT  10;
```

Comment: Start by using using [sqlformat](https://sqlformat.org/) to make this readable. You use of `NOW()` suggest this week is the result being retrieved. I'm not sure that was asked. There's some concepts here that is probably useful to the final solution so thanks for the attempt on behalf of the OP.